# Reading this link casues an error in read_excel

Tags: r, readxl

I am trying to read a excellink using read_xlsx from:
http://info.worldbank.org/governance/wgi/

I can download the file but when I try to read it using read_xlsx, I get this error message when I try the code below:

```
Error: `path` does not exist: ‘http://info.worldbank.org/governance/wgi/Home/downLoadFile?fileName=wgidataset.xlsx’
```

The code:

```
wgi_link = "http://info.worldbank.org/governance/wgi/Home/downLoadFile?fileName=wgidataset.xlsx"
readxl::read_xlsx(wgi_link, sheet = "VoiceandAccountability")
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This works fine after downloading the dataset - `readxl::read_xlsx('wgidataset.xlsx', sheet = "VoiceandAccountability", skip = 14)` . Cannot read directly from the link though.

Comment: To add to the above comment - `openxlsx` package supports reading from url. `openxlsx::read.xlsx(wgi_link, sheet = "VoiceandAccountability")
`